# Problems to include libs in my xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, charts, frameworks

I have a iOS project in Xcode 8.1 and i am trying to include Charts < https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts > to my project, but when I try to include the embedded binaries the iOS framework option don't show up. I managed to include the Swiftyjson but i cant with Charts.

print:

[image]

Comment: Does it worked?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this way.

[Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKdlVNQWVkTjZpXzg/view?usp=sharing) same code, i have integrated successfully.

[image]